# Make OneSignal work with iOS < 10.x

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, onesignal

I've integrated [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/mobile-sdk-setup) with an application. It uses an app extension with the `com.apple.usernotifications.service` value which is not available in iOS 9.x and lower. Is there a way to make the app compatible with iOS 9 even if it means disabling all notifications on those versions?

Here's the error I'm getting while running the app in an iOS 9.0 simulator:

```
Oct  8 09:00:53 users-iMac com.apple.dt.Xcode[790] <Error>: -[SimDevice _sendBridgeRequest:caller:error:]:1811 :: installApplication:withOptions:error:: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=AppexBundleUnknownExtensionPointIdentifier, ErrorDescription=Appex bundle at /Users/milad/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/***/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.AqheU6/extracted/Payload/***.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex with id com.***.ios.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension specifies a value (com.apple.usernotifications.service) for the NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in the NSExtension dictionary in its Info.plist that does not correspond to a known extension point.}
```

It works just fine in iOS 10.x and later.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was simple. My `deployment target` for the `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` target was set to 9.0, setting it to 10 fixed the issue without having to the set my main target's development target to 10.